# Logback config : How to tell if debug=true has been specified

Tags: configuration, conditional-statements, logback

In my logback.xml file I'd like to make a conditional statement that allows me to perform an action based on whether the  element was specified with the debug=true attribute.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve but obviously it doesn't work :-

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <if condition='isDefined("debug")'>
        <then>
            [..do X actions..]
        </then>
        <else>
            [.. do Y actions..]
        </else>
    </if>
</configuration>
```

I get why it doesn't work (ie. the 'debug' being set to 'true' is not a variable) so am hoping there's a way to get to the internal state of logback and then access the debug property or similar from there then I could make my condition based on that?
Can anybody help me out?

cheers in advance.